# Is there any kernel functions in Linux to convert the file descriptor to logical address in a disk drive?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

The applications in the OS will continue to access the pages in the drive via IO requests. What I want to do is to count the access times of different pages in the disk drive(may be a HDD or SSD). And I plan to implement this counting function on a linux kernel

What I'm confused is how to translate between the file descriptor and the logic address in the drive. Because the file descriptor has chance to repeat but the logic address is always unique.

I do not know how to get the logic address via the file descriptor when a IO interrupt happens. Can anyone get me some hints? Thanks.

I plan to implement it on a ubuntu 16.04 with 4.14.141 kernel.

Comment: Have you looked at `perf`, i.e. *performance counters*, what is done for this? It might be a chance that something already present in the kernel.

Comment: thanks, 0andriy, I'll check it out:)

Comment: Some additional information: Is there any kernel tool that can record the I/O traces? Trace should contain the logic address in drive.

Comment: Yes, for x86 only. It’s called *mmiotrace*. https://lwn.net/Articles/270939/

Comment: Probably there is no kernel call for that. But if you are working in the kernel space, you can develop a module what tracks the ext{234] data structures. LILO, debugfs and other tools are working by opening the block device, and interpreting the filesystem data structures on that.